# Cómo extraer el columnas que contengan el valor máximo segun otros parámetros

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una consulta corta, ya que tengo formulada casi toda el código. La consigna que poseo es la siguiente:

*Dispón airquality en formato largo y para cada variable y cada mes, extrae el día en
que cada variable tuvo el máximo valor.*

Formulé el siguiente código, pero lo que estaría necesitando es que no solo aparezca en cada lista creada el valor máximo por cada mes y variable, si no que también especifique el día correspondiente a ese valor máximo.

```
install.packages("reshape2")
library(reshape2)

airquality.long <- melt(airquality, id.vars = c("Month", "Day"))
airquality.long <- na.omit(airquality.long)

ddply(airquality.long, .(Month, variable), summarize, maxValue = max(value))
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si puedes usar `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

airquality %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(-Month, -Day)) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  slice(which.max(value))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   name [4]
  Month   Day name    value
  <int> <int> <chr>   <dbl>
1     8    25 Ozone   168  
2     5    16 Solar.R 334  
3     8    28 Temp     97  
4     6    17 Wind     20.7
```

Básicamente:

1. Con `pivot_longer` llevamos todo al formato "largo" (menos columnas `Month` y `Day`)
2. Agrupamos por la variable con `group_by(name)`
3. Nos quedamos con las filas dónde el valor sea el máximo de cada grupo.